# Cannot downgrade subversion without a lot of work

Tags: apt, svn

I'm trying to track a [bug](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/subversion_users/ApK6d5NheD8) in svn. I need to be able to switch between svn 1.7.x and 1.8.x to try tests. I am using WANdisco's packages.

/etc/issue

```
Ubuntu 12.10 \n \l
```

/etc/apt/source.list.d/WANdisco.list

```
# WANdisco Open Source Repo
deb http://opensource.wandisco.com/ubuntu precise svn18
deb http://opensource.wandisco.com/ubuntu precise svn17
```

I realise I am running Quantal but Precise is listed. This Works For Me (tm) as WANdisco doesn't have Quantal-specific packages.

When I have subversion=1.7.14-1+WANdisco installed I can

```
sudo apt-get install subversion
sudo apt-get install subversion=1.8.5-1+WANdisco
```

and either brings me up to subversion 1.8.5-1+WANdisco no problem.

Going in the other direction is a major operation. After much trial and error, here's what I've discovered/concluded is a minimal working method for me:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove subversion
sudo apt-get clean
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list.d/WANdisco.list
# deb http://opensource.wandisco.com/ubuntu precise svn18
sudo apt-get install subversion
```

As I understand this, I have to completely remove svn 1.8.5 and its dependencies (libsvn1), remove the svn 1.8.5 cached packages AND remove apt-get's knowledge that svn 1.8.x is even available. Only then will it deign to install 1.7.14.

My question is, when 1.8.5 is installed, why doesn't this

```
sudo apt-get install subversion=1.7.14-1+WANdisco
```

work? What I get is

```
user@user-VirtualBox:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ sudo apt-get install subversion=1.7.14-1+WANdisco
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 subversion : Depends: libsvn1 (= 1.7.14-1+WANdisco) but 1.8.5-1+WANdisco is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
user@user-VirtualBox:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$
```

I get the "is to be installed" unless I follow exactly all three steps above: autoremove, clean, comment out the package line.

I noticed that WANdisco's install script creates sources.list.d/WANdisco-svn1[78] so I tried using the two files instead of the one; the thinking being that perhaps line ordering in WANdisco.list was creating a priority order. That failed to downgrade in the same way. It seems that if apt-get has any knowledge that 1.8.5 exists, it will prefer that over 1.7.14.

If there's an easier way, I'd really like to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to tell apt-get to downgrade all the dependencies along:

```
sudo apt-get install subversion=1.7.14-1+WANdisco libsvn1=1.7.14-1+WANdisco
```

otherwise apt won't downgrade them. For these operations I prefer aptitude, since it allows me to resolve things manually.

Comment: I saw that people use aptitude but it wasn't installed on Quantal by default. And since apt should really handle this, I didn't want to install another tool.

Your command does work for me. Thanks. Apparently I can't upvote (posting as guest) but I can accept.

This really implies that apt has broken dependency handling though: it will satisfy dependencies when upgrading and but not when downgrading.

[And enter posts instead of newlining, and newlines are discarded. Whee.]